# What is the explicit map of the open embedding $B^- \to G/U$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, lie-groups

Let $G=GL_n$ and $B^-$ the set of lower triangular matrices in $G$. It is said that there is an open embedding $B^- \to G/U$. What is the explicit map of $B^- \to G/U$. For example, in the case of $GL_2$. We have every element in $B^-$ is of the form $\left( \begin{matrix} a & 0 \\ c & d  \end{matrix} \right)$. What is the images of elements in $B^- \to G/U$. Thank you very much.

Comment: What's $U$ denote?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $U$ is the set of *upper-triangular* unipotent matrices.  Think about $B^-\to G\to G/U$.

Comment: @Thank you very much. Yes, $U$ is upper triangular matrices. But according to your proof, it seems no matter what $U$ is, $B^- \to G/U$ is an open embedding which is not true. Where do you use the condition that $U$ is upper triangular?

Comment: You get embedding, and for openness you need to use this $U$ to count dimensions (or recall $LU$-factorisation of matrices).

Comment: thank you very much. Why LU-factorisation implies openness? For example, let $g=\left(\begin{array}{cc} a & b\\ c & d \end{array}\right)$. Then $g=b_- u = \left(\begin{array}{cc} a & 0\\ c & d - \frac{b\, c}{a} \end{array}\right) \left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & \frac{b}{a}\\ 0 & 1 \end{array}\right)$. What is the map $B^- \to G/U$ in this case?

Comment: You think of the map $G/U\to B^-$ instead, which is the "L" part of LU factorization and we know $g\mapsto(\ell,u)$ is a diffeomorphism, so projecting (univesal property of quotient) gives the induced map $G/U\to B^-$ a diffeomorphism.  The inverse map $B^-\to G/U$ maps a lower triangular matrix to its $U$-orbit in $G$.

Comment: thank you very much.

Comment: thank you very much. I am not familiar with the terminology in algebraic geometry. I would like to understand the meaning of open. Does the open mean that the image of $B^-$ is the complement of a closed subset of $G/U$? Is the closed subset defined by a system of equations? In this case, what are the equations?